Is it necessary for constant mass of system to use Newton's 2nd law?
Is it necessary for the mass of the system to be constant to use Newton's 2nd law (here the mass of the bodies in the system can change but the total mass of system can't)

Does this answer your question? Second law of Newton for variable mass systems
